# how to setup a subdomain in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, subdomain

I have my actual site running on one physical server using IIS7 and ASP.NET.  I want to add the images.mysite.com sub domain on that same server pointing to C:\MyImages folder where all my product images are.

Using IIS Management Studio I right clicked the site node, then clicked add website. entered ImageServer as my site name, set C:\MyImages as my physical path, and set image.mysite.com as my host name.

However, when I type images.mysite.com/myfirstimage.jpg in a browser I get Firefox can't find the server at images.mysite.com.

What am I missing? What else needs to be done?  I called my DNS registrar and they said I do not need to register subdomains with them.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you add a A record in your DNS server? Try ping images.mysite.com and see if that's the IP you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks! With my domain registrar or do i need to add dns server to my windows server that is going to be holding my images?

Comment: No, seems that you already have dns server. www.mysite.com works right? So just go to registrar and update the dns record.

Comment: Thanks ysrb. I did as you said and it works like a charm :) If you copy and paste your comment into an answer then I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you add a A record in your DNS server. Try ping images.mysite.com and see if that's the IP you are expecting.